# How do I defend myself against the eagles?

Tags: far-cry-4

Every once in a while, an eagle will attack me from the sky while I'm outside, like how [this video perfectly illustrates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi8Xoc4EInE). How can I defend myself against them, besides shooting them before and after they attack me?

Is there a way to melee them when they are close, for instance? I don't recall there being a key prompt when they are attacking me though, like there are with other animals, like the crocodile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to defend yourself against eagles once they attack you.

You can try to spot them before they swoop down and attack you, but you're going to look like a crazy person looking up every 5 seconds.

[image]

Comment: I think the eagles also cry out every once in a while, when they are near you. I notice that they don't always attack even after they cry out, though.

Comment: Suck it up with the rest of us brother, they only reduce 1 bar of health after they attack. My suggestion is to upgrade your health bars to 4 a.s.a.p

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably have to drop a point or two in health. I'm still at 2.

Comment: Is this the same for all animal attacks? Essentially meaning that you have to damage them before they get into your face?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to shake or melee them, but shooting them before (or after if needed) is a good approach and isn't that hard.

**1 - The Warning Cry**

While it's true that eagles occasionally give a single, long call, before attacking they give a very distinctive cry: three high-pitched "skrees" in quick succession. Sometimes these are followed by the standard call.

The next time an eagle attacks you, just stand there for a while and let it come back for successive attacks, healing as needed, and learn to recognize the attack cry.

Over time that cry will probably start giving you an unpleasant jolt even if you're not specifically listening for it. (Thank you, Dr. Pavlov.)

**2 - Initial Defense**

When you hear the attack cry, either head for cover or look up quickly to counter-attack. From the start of the first "skree" you'll have 3-5 seconds until that unpleasant bird-bite cut scene.

With luck that'll give you time to look up and switch to an appropriate weapon. Shotguns or guns with a high fire rate (machine, SMG) are ideal.

**3 - Payback**

If you don't kill it the first time around, quickly switch to your camera and tag it, then wait. If you stay in the same area it should attack again fairly soon, and this time you'll be ready to eliminate the threat.

Answer (score 0):

You can always run as fast as you can through vegetation. Usually a tree will get in the way and you'll be fine. Works for most predators and enemies as well, really.